# Menu dropdown transition won't work (CSS only)

Tags: html, css

Can someone please help me do dropdown transition here... ?
On hover the dropdown should show up in fade-in manner. This is really confusing because right transition is not working no matter where I apply it. This colorful menu is just an example to get the right idea on how to make the dropdown transition work. I just need a simple ease-in transition that will work. I have been trying hard to fix this. Help is greatly appreciated.

```html
<ul id='nav'>
    <li class='menuitem1'>mainmenu1
        <ul>
            <li class='menuitem1'>Menu 111</li>
            <li class='menuitem1'>Menu 22</li>
            <li class='menuitem1'>Menu 3333</li>
            <li class='menuitem1'>Menu 44
        </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  
    <li class='menuitem2'>Menu3774 
    <ul>
            <li class='menuitem2'>Menu 111</li>
            <li class='menuitem2'>Menu 22</li>
            <li class='menuitem2'>Menu 3333</li>
            <li class='menuitem2'>Menu 44
        </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li class='menuitem3'>Menury 
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>

<style>
.menuitem1 {
    background:#4dd2ff;
}
.menuitem1:hover {
     color:#000;
    background:#94e4ff;
}

.menuitem2 {
    background:#1aff8c;
}

.menuitem2:hover {
    background:#87ffc3;
}

.menuitem3 {
    background:#d2a679;
}
.menuitem3:hover {
    background:#f5c89a;
}

   
nav > ul {
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

#nav {
    display:table;
      margin:0;
  }
#nav > li {
    cursor:pointer;
    list-style:none;
    padding:12px 0;
    border:1px #959696 solid;
    position:relative;
    display:table-cell;
    width:1%;
    text-align:center;
    
}


#nav ul li {
    width: 250px;
    display:block;
    padding:3px 20px;
    text-indent:0;
    line-height:40px;
    text-align:left;
    border-top:1px #fff solid;
    border-bottom:1px #fff solid;
    border-left:none;
    border-right:none;
    position:relative;
    
}

#nav ul {
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    max-height:300px;
    position:absolute;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
        transition: height 0.3s ease-in;

}
#nav li:hover > ul {
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}


ul {
    display:none;
}
li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1000;
    border:1px #fff solid;
    margin-top:12px;
    margin-left:0;

}   
#nav > li ul li ul {

    left:100%;
    top:-2px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    
}
#nav li:hover > a, #nav li:hover {

}
li, li a {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    
}
* {box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The transition becomes broken by the conflicting #nav styles you have for the menu. Creating class names is generally a recommended practice. I would reference the following example written on CodePen: https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/gsFch

```html
    <nav>
       <ul>
         <li class="sub-menu-parent" tab-index="0">
           <a href="http://google.com">Menu Item 1</a>
           <ul class="sub-menu">
             <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
         <li class="sub-menu-parent" tab-index="0">
           <a href="#">Menu Item 2</a>
           <ul class="sub-menu">
             <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Sub Item 5</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Sub Item 6</a></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
         <li class="sub-menu-parent" tab-index="0">
           <a href="#">Menu Item 3</a>
           <ul class="sub-menu">
             <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
           </ul></li>
       </ul>
     </nav>

<style>

.sub-menu-parent { position: relative; }

.sub-menu { 
  visibility: hidden; /* hides sub-menu */
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-2em);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s, visibility 0s linear 0.3s, z-index 0s linear 0.01s;
}

.sub-menu-parent:focus .sub-menu,
.sub-menu-parent:focus-within .sub-menu,
.sub-menu-parent:hover .sub-menu {
  visibility: visible; /* shows sub-menu */
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.3s; /* this removes the transition delay so the menu will be visible while the other styles transition */
}

/* presentational */
body { padding: 2%; font: 18px/1.4 sans-serif; }

nav a { color: #E00; display: block; padding: 0.5em 1em; text-decoration: none; }
nav a:hover { color: #F55; }
nav ul,
nav ul li { list-style-type: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; }

nav > ul { background: #EEE; text-align: center; }
nav > ul > li { display: inline-block; border-left: solid 1px #aaa; }
nav > ul > li:first-child { border-left: none; }

.sub-menu {
  background: #DDD;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

The action you want to do is css animation. Animation duration "animation-duration: 4s;" You can adjust it according to you. You can edit the transitions you want to do with "@keyframes example". For more information you can check here. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

```css
   .menuitem1 {
        background:#4dd2ff;
    }
    .menuitem1:hover {
         color:#000;
        background:#94e4ff;
    }

    .menuitem2 {
        background:#1aff8c;
    }

    .menuitem2:hover {
        background:#87ffc3;
    }

    .menuitem3 {
        background:#d2a679;
    }
    .menuitem3:hover {
        background:#f5c89a;
    }

       
    nav > ul {
        transition-duration: 0.5s;
    }

    #nav {
        display:table;
          margin:0;
      }
    #nav > li {
        cursor:pointer;
        list-style:none;
        padding:12px 0;
        border:1px #959696 solid;
        position:relative;
        display:table-cell;
        width:1%;
        text-align:center;
        
    }


    #nav ul li {
      animation-name: example;
        animation-duration: 4s;
        width: 250px;
        display:block;
        padding:3px 20px;
        text-indent:0;
        line-height:40px;
        text-align:left;
        border-top:1px #fff solid;
        border-bottom:1px #fff solid;
        border-left:none;
        border-right:none;
        position:relative;


    }

@keyframes example {
  from {background-color: #94e4ff00;}
  to {background-color: #94e4ff;}
  
  from {color: #94e4ff00;}
  to {color: black;}
}

    #nav ul {
        visibility:hidden;
        opacity:0;
        max-height:300px;
        position:absolute;
        filter:alpha(opacity=0);
            transition: height 0.3s ease-in;

    }
    #nav li:hover > ul {
        visibility:visible;
        opacity:1;
        filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    }


    ul {
        display:none;
                
    }
    li:hover > ul {
  
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:1000;
        border:1px #fff solid;
        margin-top:12px;
        margin-left:0;

    }   
    #nav > li ul li ul {

        left:100%;
        top:-2px;
        white-space:nowrap;
        
    }
    #nav li:hover > a, #nav li:hover {

    }
    li, li a {
        color:#000;
        text-decoration:none;
        
    }
    * {box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;}
```

```html
    <ul id='nav'>
        <li class='menuitem1'>mainmenu1
            <ul>
                <li class='menuitem1'>Menu 111</li>
                <li class='menuitem1'>Menu 22</li>
                <li class='menuitem1'>Menu 3333</li>
                <li class='menuitem1'>Menu 44
            </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      
        <li class='menuitem2'>Menu3774 
        <ul>
                <li class='menuitem2'>Menu 111</li>
                <li class='menuitem2'>Menu 22</li>
                <li class='menuitem2'>Menu 3333</li>
                <li class='menuitem2'>Menu 44
            </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        
        <li class='menuitem3'>Menury 
        </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: You fixed my actual problem. Thank you.